# Cannot get nested routes in Angular to show up in the view

Tags: html, angular, typescript, single-page-application, angular-router

I am having all sorts of trouble with child/nested routes in Angular 4.  In the imports statement in app.module.ts, I have:

```
    RouterModule.forRoot([
        {
            path: 'templates',
            component: TemplateLandingComponent,
            children: [
                {path: 'main-templates', component: MainTemplateComponent}
            ]
        },
    ])
```

In my main nav, I have the following:

```
<li><a [routerLink]="['/templates']" [routerLinkActive]="'active'">Templates</a></li>
```

This works fine and takes me to the parent TemplateLandingComponent.  Then I have another link in the TemplateLandingComponent:

```
<li><a [routerLink]="['/templates/main-templates']" [routerLinkActive]="'active'">Active Templates</a></li>
```

Clicking on this link routes to the proper url but does not show my MainTemplateComponent.  What am I doing wrong?

Even if I manually navigate to /templates/main-templates I still only see the TemplateLandingComponent

Comment: Have you added router outlet inside you templateLandingComponent

Comment: I have added the router-outlet to my app.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<li><a routerLink="/main-templates" [routerLinkActive]="'active'">Active Templates</a></li>
```

Change your routes to this

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
    {
        path: 'templates',
        children: [
           {path: '', component: TemplateLandingComponent}
            {path: 'main-templates', component: MainTemplateComponent}
        ]
    },
])
```

or insert `<router-outlet>` in your TemplateLandingComponent.
 It depends what you want if its 2 separate components write your routerModule that i wrote. It its parent child component use router-outlet in parent component.

routerLink will navigate relative to your current path not absolute path.

Comment: This still just shows my TemplateLandingComponent.  The core issue is that even navigating (manually) to /templates/main-templates does not properly route to my MainTemplateComponent

Comment: can you please insert <router-outlet> in your templateLandingComponent and then manually navigate where you want?